# Azure deployment : Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc

Create a new ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6) app and deploy to Azure. You get the HTTP 500 exception. If you create a *web.config* file in the wwwroot folder with the following markup:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You get the the exception in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get this error is to deploy a 64 bit version (either Core or x86) to a free or shared web app. If you create the azure web app in the publish dialog, VS creates a free web app (which doesn't support 64 bit).

Comment: I have just installed VS 2015 and built an ASP.NET 5 application. Then ran the 'dnu restore' command after seeing references error. When I build it and run in my browser, I get the same error as the title of this question. Can you recommend a way out?

Answer (score 1):

When you publish in Visual studio 2015 RC, in the publish web "setting": you should choose "dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta4", not dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4.

Comment: You can't run 64 bit apps (core or full CLR) in the free web apps you create from the VS 2015 RC publish wizard. Did you mean the opposite of what you wrote? Free/shared web apps won't run 64 bit.