# Missing assembly 'dnx.clr.managed'

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net-core

I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET 5 application to my 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2 server. I created a blank web application and set up a file system publish profile using dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta4. I copied the results from the publish location to a folder on my server and created a new virtual directory with a .NET 4.0 app pool pointing at the wwwroot folder of my application. However, when I try to browse to the site, I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

The same steps on my local PC (where I have Visual Studio 2015 installed) work correctly so it seems like I need to install something else on my server. I have already installed .NET 4.6 on this server without success. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: how do you publish your application? you need to use `--runtime` switch for `dnu publish` command (`--runtime active` for active runtime).

Comment: I am publishing from Visual Studio so I'm just using what ever the GUI generates.

Comment: @tugberk I am getting the same error on localhost. Can any one recommend a way out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to this question: [Azure deployment : Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316182/azure-deployment-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-dnx-clr-managed-or-one-of-i)

At first I thought that wasn't the answer because it didn't work when I changed my publish profile from dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta4 to dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta4. However, I later noticed that approot/packages folder didn't have the x64 package. So I deleted everything and re-published with my new profile and the page loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Change the dependencies file to the current version, whether it is 1.0.0-beta7 or 1.0.0-beta6 ensure that you go to nuget package manager and install the appropriate version rebuild the solution you should see file updates from your output windows.